# Increasing/ Decreasing Annuity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can we evaluate $c$ such that the following series converges using the definition of limit of a sequence?
$$
s{_n}=\sum_{t=1}^{n}tc^{t}, c\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You could write $$s{_n}=\sum_{t=1}^{n}tc^{t}=c\sum_{t=1}^{n}tc^{t-1}$$ and recognize that the right hand side summation is just the derivative of $ z=\sum_{t=1}^{n}c^{t}$ with respect ot $c$ and that this is a geometric progression. So, compute $z$, diffrentiate it with respect to $c$, multiply the result by $c$ and conclude.

I am sure that you can take from hers.

Answer (score 0):

For $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$,
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{(t+1)c}{t}\right|<1\\
\implies |c|<1$$